# Optimal partitioning of a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request, optimization

I found the following problem in Graph Theory which states that:

> For every simple undirected graph, there is a way of partitioning the set of vertices in two blocks such that every vertex in a block has at least half of its neighbors in the other block.

The solution I found was based on the idea that: if the partition is such that there is a maximum number of edges between the two blocks, than the partition satisfies the required property. I am not sure about the converse, but there was no need to have equivalence between the two properties in order to solve the problem.

Also, the above solution provides a way of constructing such a partition (by starting with an arbitrary partition and moving vertices from one block to the other, when the vertices do not satisfy the property required for the partition).

Is there an algorithmic approach to this problem to find ALL the partitions with the required conditions? Do you know if this has been studied somewhere in more detail?